# Почему в группе команды бота работают и дублируют ответ на сообщение в группе?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, python-telegram-bot

Я сделал бота который пересылает сообщение пользователя в закрытую группу. Дальше в группе админ отвечает на сообщение через reply и ответ присылается пользователю. Проблема в том что команды бота(например /start) работает в закрытой группе, вторая проблема когда админ отвечает на сообщение в группе бот дублирует ответ в группе(грубо говоря бот в группе реагирует на любой текст и дублирует его). Как это исправить?

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types='text')
async def get_message(message: types.Message):
    await message.forward(PRIVATE_GROUP, message.text)
    # когда админ отвечает на сообщение вернуть ответ пользователю
    # почему команда /start работает в группе?
    # почему бот дублирует ответ в группе?
    if message.reply_to_message and message.chat.id == PRIVATE_GROUP and message.text != '/start':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, message.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простым решением будет фильтр - не выполняем действие когда chat_id сообщения совпадает с chat_id группы.
В коде это выглядит так:

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types='text')
async def get_message(message: types.Message):

    #если chat_id сообщения == chat_id группы - не пересылаем
    if message.chat.id!=PRIVATE_GROUP:
        await message.forward(PRIVATE_GROUP, message.text)

    elif message.reply_to_message:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, message.text)
```